# not able to logout in pinterest in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, pinterest

i am integrating Pinterest login in my swift app but the issue is that i am login success fully but when i click on button logout i am not able to logout here is my code

**Code**

```
    @IBAction func btnLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {
            PDKClient.sharedInstance().authenticate(withPermissions: [PDKClientReadPublicPermissions,PDKClientWritePublicPermissions,PDKClientReadRelationshipsPermissions,PDKClientWriteRelationshipsPermissions], withSuccess: { (PDKResponseObject) in


                self.accessToken = PDKClient.sharedInstance().oauthToken


                //MARK: - Getting User Profile, use "/v1/me" to get user data in the Response object -

                let parameters : [String:String] =
                    [

                        "fields":  "first_name,id,last_name,url,image,username,bio,counts,created_at,account_type" //these fields will be fetched for the loggd in user
                ]

                PDKClient.sharedInstance().getPath("/v1/me/", parameters: parameters, withSuccess: {

                    (PDKResponseObject) in
                    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

                     self.user = (PDKResponseObject?.user())!
                    print(PDKResponseObject!)
                    self.lblUserName.text = PDKResponseObject?.user().username
                    if let url = JSON(PDKResponseObject?.user().images["60x60"] as Any)["url"].string
                    {
                        self.imgProPic.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: url))
                    }

                }) {
                    (Error) in
                    if let error = Error
                    {
                        print("\(Error)")
                    }
                    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                    PDKPinError.unknown
                }

            }) {
                (Error) in
                self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            }
        }
        @IBAction func btnLogout(_ sender: UIButton) {
       /*
            let cookieJar : HTTPCookieStorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
            for cookie in cookieJar.cookies! as [HTTPCookie]{
            NSLog("cookie.domain = %@", cookie.domain)

            if cookie.domain == "www.pinterest.com" ||
                cookie.domain == "api.pinterest.com"{

                cookieJar.deleteCookie(cookie)
            }
        }
       */
            PDKClient.clearAuthorizedUser()
        }
```

here i have done clearAuthorizedUser() but not logged out and also i have done cookie clear code but thats not working please help me to solve this

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue, and I thought I might be able to help someone by posting my solution here. The app that I'm maintaining authenticates Pinterest by loading "https://api.pinterest.com/oauth/" in a UIWebView with the appropriate parameters. This authentication approach does not require the Pinterest SDK and is explained in detail here: https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/. I was able to add a button that the user can tap to log them out of their authenticated Pinterest account. To log the user out, I removed all cookies associated with Pinterest Authentication, and removed any stored authentication token. Below is the code I use to remove the cookies:

```
let cookieJar: HTTPCookieStorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
 if let cookies: [HTTPCookie] = cookieJar.cookies {
     for cookie in cookies {
         let domain = cookie.domain
         if domain == "accounts-oauth.pinterest.com"
                    || domain == ".pinterest.com"
                    || domain == ".facebook.com"
                    || domain == "accounts.google.com" {
             cookieJar.deleteCookie(cookie)
         }
     }
 }
```

After that, you will most likely need to call PDKClient.clearAuthorizedUser() to remove any stored authentication token.